# typename in Templates in C++

Tags: c++, templates

What is the difference between following two usages of templates?

Usage 1:

```
template<class T> class U : A<T>
{
  T::B x;
  void f(A<T>& y) { *y++; }
};
```

Usage 2:

```
template<class T> class U : A<T>
{
  typename T::B x;
  void f(A<T>& y) { *y++; }
};
```

Is there any ambiguity in 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that "Usage 1" should not compile.  When a dependent name like `T::B` is not preceded by `typename`, it is assumed to refer to an object or function member.  In which case, `T::B x;` is invalid syntax.

Answer (score 3):

According to the standard, $14.6/2 Name resolution [temp.res]

> A name used in a template declaration or definition and that is
>   dependent on a template-parameter is assumed not to name a type unless
>   the applicable name lookup finds a type name or the name is qualified
>   by the keyword typename.

That means, if you don't use the keyword `typename` for `T::B x;`, `T::B` will be considered as a non-type name, such as a member `B` of `T`, whick makes `T::B x;` ill-formed.